# Error deploying redis local cluster on windows

Tags: windows, redis

" Synchronization with replica 127.0.0.1:6382 succeeded" appears in port 6379,then the following error occurs on my port 6382：
[14972] 07 Aug 11:17:30.835 # Reading the configuration file, at line 0

[14972] 07 Aug 11:17:30.835 # >>> '(null)'

[14972] 07 Aug 11:17:30.835 # replicaof directive not allowed in cluster mode

[28648] 07 Aug 11:17:30.897 # fork operation failed
[28648] 07 Aug 11:17:30.905 # Background AOF rewrite terminated by signal 1
[28648] 07 Aug 11:17:31.039 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 20688
[20688] 07 Aug 11:17:31.092 #
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***

- Clear FAIL state for node 558280e1d0b98a7a43668dfb19c6fab409cfce45: replica is reachable again.

Please help me!

I've checked that the port number in the config file is correct.